# How to put condition inside function of a dojo

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo

I might not be able to explain the structure of dojo function in the header but this is what i am looking for 
Here is my existing function

```
createClient: function () {
            var clientWizardData = this.getNewClientWizardData(),

                clientSummaryFormData = clientWizardData.clientSummaryFormData,
                subscribedProducts = clientSubscriptionFormData.products,
                createClientRequest;

            createClientRequest = {
                "subscriptionMode": clientSubscriptionFormData.mode,
                "products": subscribedProducts,
                "subscriptionType": clientSubscriptionFormData.subscriptionType,
                "subscriptionStartDate": formatters.toVPDateBoundedJSON(clientSubscriptionFormData.subscriptionFromDate, true),
                "clientFinalised": clientSummaryFormData.isClientFinalise
            };
        },
```

And i want to put if condition in `createClientRequest` function

The condition is something like this

```
if(toggleableFeatures.has(globals.toggleableFeatures.INCLUDE_EXCLUDE_ALIASES_ALTERNATIVE_SPELLING)){
            "aliases": clientSubscriptionFormData.aliases,
            "alternativeSpelling": clientSubscriptionFormData.alternativeSpelling,
            "excludeLowQualityAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.excludeLowQualityAkas,
            "includeNativeAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.includeNativeAkas
    }else{
            "excludeLowQualityAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.excludeLowQualityAkas,
            "includeNativeAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.includeNativeAkas
    }
```

Can some one help me with the syntax here please .Putting if else directly does not work 
Do i have to create any function and then call this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
"clientFinalised": clientSummaryFormData.isClientFinalise,
                "if": {"toggleableFeatures": globals.toggleableFeatures.INCLUDE_EXCLUDE_ALIASES_ALTERNATIVE_SPELLING },
                "then": {"aliases": clientSubscriptionFormData.aliases,"alternativeSpelling": clientSubscriptionFormData.alternativeSpelling,"excludeLowQualityAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.excludeLowQualityAkas,"includeNativeAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.includeNativeAkas },
                "else": {
                    "excludeLowQualityAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.excludeLowQualityAkas,
                    "includeNativeAkas": clientSubscriptionFormData.includeNativeAkas
                },
            };
```